# How to add a threshold/conditional computation to a funtion in R?

Tags: r

I have been struggling with writing a function to compute correlations that is conditional on the number of complete cases being bigger than a certain number (otherwise returns 0 for correlation).

The issue is how to add the threshold. See below my formula that only computes the correlations per file and prints them.

I have added
               if (complete > treshhold)  but it does not seem to do anything.

Thank you in advance! 
Susan

```
            corr<-function(directory,treshhold=0){
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  mydata <- data.frame()
  treshhold<-vector(,1)
  cr<-vector(,332)


        for (i in 1:332){                                
        mydata <- read.csv(files_list[i])
        complete<-sum(complete.cases(mydata))

           if (complete > treshhold) {        
           x<- cor(mydata$sulfate,mydata$nitrate,use="complete.obs")            

           cr<-c(x)
           print(cr)
           } else{
           x<-0
           }
       } 
  }
```

Comment: what is the value of `treshhold` and why is it vector? By default a vector will be logical, and interestingly in R even `1 > TRUE`

Comment: Hi R.S., The threshold is user defined each time for example corr("specdata", 150) There is no specific number. Also because the correlation is computed per file i suppose a vector with threshold is needed for each file, i am not sure if that is the case. Could you help me out with this information ?